# binding form parameters to a bean using just Servlets and JSP - possible?

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, javabeans

I am using Servlet and JSP without a framework to study for my SCWCD.  I have a simple form that I want the parameters to bind to a bean automatically.  Is this possible without writing binding code or using a framework?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it isn't. You should use some framework, which I guess would be an overkill.

So what you can do, is iterate `request.getParameterMap()` keys and set the values to object with the corresponding field names (via reflection)

Comment: Fulvius answer provides an alternative without directly using reflection.

Answer (score 11):

Well, without a "framework" you can't do this. But you can use the Jakarta BeanUtils (http://commons.apache.org/beanutils/), more precisely the static method `BeanUtils.populate` in your servlet. Ex.:

```
BeanUtils.populate (myBean, request.getParameterMap());
```

Remember: the input properties names must match with bean attributes, ok?

Answer (score 9):

You can do this with `<jsp:useBean>`.

```
<jsp:useBean id="form" class="com.example.Form" scope="request" />
<jsp:setProperty name="form" property="*" />
<jsp:include page="servletUrl" />
```

All bean properties whose names match the request parameter names -if any- will be set and the bean will be available as request attribute in the servlet matching the `url-pattern` of `/servletUrl`.

However, you'd like to use a servlet and/or MVC framework for this since it abstracts it all away and gives a better control over actions and response handling. This is essentially abuse of JSP (as being a view technology) as controller (which should be (in)directly done by a Servlet).