# Passing an object from JSP page back to Servlet

Tags: jsp, object, servlets

In short, I want to know how to pass an `object` from JSP page back to a Servlet. Specifically, I have a form element whose action tag references a servlet. On form submission, I want to embed an `object` in `HttpServletRequest` request `object` so that it can be dereferenced by servlet.

So far, I have tried setting `request.setAttribute(object)` in JSP page. But still retrieving it from servlet gives it as null. Any pointers would be appreciated.

Comment: possible duplicate of [send object from JSP to sevlet](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3857594/send-object-from-jsp-to-sevlet)

Comment: Not quite the same. Anyways, the link was barely informative.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Learn how HTTP works:

- Client (usually, a web browser) fires HTTP request.
- Server retrieves HTTP request.
- Servletcontainer creates **new** `HttpServletRequest` and `HttpServletResponse` objects.
- Servletcontainer invokes appropriate servlet with those objects.
- Servlet processes request and forwards request and response to JSP.
- JSP writes to the response body.
- Servletcontainer commits HTTP response and **destroys** request and response objects.
- Server sends HTTP response back to client.
- Client retrieves HTTP response and processes it (display HTML, apply CSS, execute JS).

When you send a new request by submitting the form, it won't reuse the same request and response objects.

There are two ways to overcome this stateless nature of HTTP. You need to convert this object to `String` and include it in a hidden input field of the HTML form in the JSP so that it'll be available as request parameter upon submission.

```
<input type="hidden" name="myObject" value="${myObjectAsString}" />
```

The conversion to `String` is necessary because HTTP and HTML doesn't understand Java objects. HTML is in Java's perspective basically one large `String` (do a rightclick and *View Source* in webbrowser to see it). If you don't convert a Java object to `String`, then by default Java object's `toString()` result will be printed to HTML, which is not per definition convertible back to the original Java object. Most commonly used `String` formats of complex objects are JSON and XML. There are a lot of Java libraries available which can convert between complex Java objects and a `String` in JSON or XML format.

Or, if the object is too large or too complex to be converted to `String` and vice versa, then you need to store it in the server's memory or in some database and instead pass its unique identifier around as hidden input value. Usually the session scope is been used for this.

So, in the servlet which prepares the data and forwards to the 
JSP page:

```
String myObjectId = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
request.getSession().setAttribute(myObjectId, myObject);
request.setAttribute("myObjectId", myObjectId);
request.getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/page.jsp").forward(request, response);
```

And, in the forwarded JSP page:

```
<form action="nextservlet" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="myObjectId" value="${myObjectId}" />
    ...
</form>
```

Finally, in the next servlet which processes the form submit:

```
String myObjectId = request.getParameter("myObjectId");
Object myObject = request.getSession().getAttribute(myObjectId);
request.getSession().removeAttribute(myObjectId);
// ...
```

#### See also:

- [How do servlets work? Instantiation, sessions, shared variables and multithreading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3106452/java-servlet-instantiation-and-session-variables)
- [How can I store state for an individual browser tab/window?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13292395/how-to-store-data-for-every-individual-browser-tab-window-the-session-scope-is/)

Comment: Out of the 2 approaches you suggested, when we want to take input from client through a form in an HTML page, I think the only option available is option 1 - converting it into a sting and then again breaking the string and creating our own objects in the servlet. Correct? I don't see how option 2 can be used in that case. Am I right?

Answer (score 2):

once the JSP is rendered the request object is over. So the object you set on request of JSP is available for that JSP page request alone. Do you have any constraint on using session instead of request. So, session can hold data between fresh requests until the session expires.

Answer (score 2):

Best way is to encode Java object in base64 and then pass it as a String from JSP to servlet.

For example -

```
final ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
final ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(baos);
oos.writeObject(javaObject);
oos.flush();
final String result = new String(Base64.getEncoder().encode(baos.toByteArray()));
```

Pass this result in HTTP request -

```
   <input type = "hidden" name="<%= "MY_JAVA_OBJECT" %>" value="<%= result  %>" />
```

Read it on server back to java object -

```
final String base64String = request.getparameter("MY_JAVA_OBJECT");
final byte[] objToBytes = Base64.getDecoder().decode(base64String);
ByteArrayInputStream bais = new ByteArrayInputStream(objToBytes);
ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(bais);
return (ObjectClass) ois.readObject();
```

Comment: How do I pass the HTTP tag "<input type..." in the HTTP request? Please help.