# how to send an object from jsp to servlet

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Passing Object from JSP to Servlet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4253660/passing-object-from-jsp-to-servlet)

I have an object that is being sent successfully from a servlet to a jsp.
In that jsp page I have a button and when user click on that button the same object should be sent from that jsp page to another servlet. how can I do that ??

Answer (score 4):

Send it as request attribut when clicking on button
a) Set request attrbute in jsp

```
request.setAttribute("thatobject",thatobject);
```

In Servlet retrive it as

```
Thatobject obj = (ThatObject) request.getAttribute("thatobject");
```

b) Set the object in session `session.setAttribute("thatobject",thatobject)`
and retrive it as

```
Thatobject obj = (ThatObject) session.getAttribute("thatobject");
```

Oh my mistake Updated...

**Note:** Also iam not providing null check. I think you can handle it

***Edit:***

Even you can do other way, which is very sofistiacted way,

a) Create a Bean class
b) provide Object as a attribute in bean class and provide getter and setter methods too
C) in jsp use that bean to set the object when the page is submitting to servlet
d) retrive the object from the bean in servelt

**Edit 2:**

Please check this link there is clear explanation.
[JSP2Servlet](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/A97336_01/buslog.102/a83726/basics4.htm#1014142)

***Edit 3***

Note : **If you are submiting form , the request becomes new request and the object will become null, when you use request.getattribute in servlet. So above approach will not work on Form submit in jsp.**

So to overcome this please folw the instructions provide in below link

[Passing Object from JSP to Servlet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4253660/passing-object-from-jsp-to-servlet)

Comment: Damodar check the return type of the getParameter method, it will return only a String, so ur snippet will fail. it should be something like this   `String userName = request.getParameter("userName");`

Comment: Great Damodar. Jigar thats the way to do it, if you do not require an updated object.

Comment: I provide for updated object too

Comment: @Damodar: This won't work either. `.setAttribute()` always returns null when you try to get them on servlet.

Comment: @HardikMishra Please can you explain why it wnot works

Comment: how can I forward that object from the jsp page?

Comment: request.setAttribute("thatobject",thatobject);

Comment: @Damodar: Please try your self that setting `request.setAttribute` in JSP will result NULL when you access it from Servlet using `request.getAttribute()`.

Comment: @HardikMishra you mean even Java doc says wrong. Please check the below url http://docs.oracle.com/cd/A97336_01/buslog.102/a83726/basics4.htm#1014142 .Please check code under Code for Jsp2Servlet.jsp otherwise give me the reason behind to make your statement strong

Comment: @Damodar: The link says "Invoking a JSP Page from a Servlet" which is correct. Here You are talking about 'Servlet to JSP' which is different. No hard feelings.

Comment: @HardikMishra  please did you check at the bottom with heading "JSP-Servlet Interaction Samples"

Comment: @Damodar: It works as per given example. but when you submit form it does not. Clarify your answer then. :)

Comment: @HardikMishra you mean, on form submission do that value of the object becomes null?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/11509/discussion-between-hardik-mishra-and-damodar)