# hidden input from JSP to Controller

Tags: jsp, controller, hidden

Im trying to send data from JSP to Controller.

I have smth like that in my JSP:

```
..
<form action="add.html" method="get">
<input type="hidden" name="type" value="<c:out value='${type}'/>"/>
<input type="submit" value="Add">
</form>
.. 
<input type="text" name="type">
```

What should i write instead of attr value to pass data?

Answer (score 3):

If a field is hidden, you typically are passing it down because you need it after the form is submitted. It's like a final variable that shouldn't be changed.

So you either want:

```
<form action="add.html" method="get">
    <input type="hidden" name="myValueAttr" value="${myValueAttr}" />
    <input type="submit" value="Add">
</form>
```

Or:

```
<form action="add.html" method="get">
    <input type="text" name="myValueAttr" />
    <input type="submit" value="Add">
</form>
```

I'm guessing you want the latter.
Here is a link to a full explanation: [Passing an object from JSP page back to Servlet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4253660/passing-object-from-jsp-to-servlet?answertab=active#tab-top)