# How to correctly pass data from Servlet to JSP?

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I need to pass data from Servlet (which it gets from DAO) to JSP. The wrong data ends up in JSP (with overhead of html code from Servlet). How it ends up there? How to correctly handle this situation?

**Servlet:**

```
@Override
    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws IOException, ServletException {

String reqId = request.getParameter("id");
        Integer reqIdInt = null;
        String tempHTML = "";

        try {
            reqIdInt = Integer.parseInt(reqId);
            } catch (NumberFormatException e) {    }
        /**
         * findById()
         */
        if (reqIdInt != null) {
            // s?id=.....
            DSLR dslr = dslrDAO.findById(reqIdInt);

            if(dslr != null){
                tempHTML ="<form action=\"s?action=save\" method=\"POST\">\n" +
                        "\n" +
                        "<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"id\" value=\""+dslr.getDslrId()+"\">\n" +
                        "\n" +
                        "\n" +
                        "<table bgcolor=\"#000000\" border=\"0\" cellpadding=\"0\" cellspacing=\"0\"><tbody><tr><td><table  border=\"0\" cellpadding=\"2\" cellspacing=\"1\">\n" +
                        "<tbody><tr bgcolor=\"#ffffff\"><td bgcolor=\"#cccccc\" nowrap=\"\">id:</td><td>"+dslr.getDslrId()+"</td></tr>\n" +
                        "<tr bgcolor=\"#ffffff\"><td bgcolor=\"#cccccc\" nowrap=\"\">model:</td><td>&nbsp;<b><font color=\"#0000ff\"><input type=\"text\" value=\""+dslr.getModel()+"\" name=\"model\"></font></b></td></tr>\n" +
                        "<tr bgcolor=\"#ffffff\"><td bgcolor=\"#cccccc\" nowrap=\"\">price:</td><td>&nbsp;<b><font color=\"#0000ff\"><input type=\"text\" value=\""+dslr.getPrice()+"\" name=\"price\"></font></b></td></tr>\n" +
                        "<tr bgcolor=\"#ffffff\"><td bgcolor=\"#cccccc\" nowrap=\"\">description:</td><td>&nbsp;<b><font color=\"#0000ff\"><textarea name=\"description\" cols=\"25\" rows=\"6\">"+dslr.getDescription()+"</font></b></td></tr>\n" +
                        "</tbody></table></td></tr></tbody></table>\n" +
                        "<input type=\"submit\" value=\"savedata\">\n" +
                        "</form>" +
                        "<tr><td>" + dslr.getDslrId() +
                        "</td><td>" + dslr.getModel() +
                        "</td><td>" + dslr.getPrice() +
                        "</td><td><a href=\"javascript:get_dslr(" + dslr.getDslrId() + ") target=\"_self\"\">" + dslr.getDescription() +
                        "</td><td><a href=\"" + "s?id=" + dslr.getDslrId() + "\">modify</a></td></tr>";

//                request.getSession().setAttribute("generatedResponse",tempHTML);
                request.setAttribute("generatedResponse",tempHTML);
                request.getRequestDispatcher("/dslrs.jsp").forward(request, response);
            }
}
```

**JSP**

```
...

<%=(String)request.getAttribute("generatedResponse")%>
...
```

The browser:

[image]

---

UPDATE:

Screenshot shows the excessive HTML (which is somehow dragged from servlet or jsp and put in `description` text field, for example: `</html>`). The form data which is wrong is highlighted (yellow) for clarity I don't need to customize font of text area.

---

UPDATE2:

I managed to handle messy code in Servlet but I still don't like to store HTML in Servlet. I'd like to have there only logic. I don't want to put HTML generation directly to JSP. How to separate logic from HTml in this example?

**new Servlet doGet method:**

```
    String reqId = request.getParameter("id");
    Integer reqIdInt = null;
    String tempHTML = "";

    try {
        reqIdInt = Integer.parseInt(reqId);
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {    }
    /**
     * findById()
     */
    if (reqIdInt != null) {
        // s?id=.....
        DSLR dslr = dslrDAO.findById(reqIdInt);

        if(dslr != null){
            tempHTML = "<form action=\"s?action=save\" method=\"POST\">\n" +
                    "<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"id\"  value=\""+dslr.getDslrId()+"\">\n" +
                    "\t<table class=\"table\" bgcolor=\"#000000\" border=\"0\">\n" +
                    "\t\t<tr>\n" +
                    "\t\t\t<td>id:</td>\n" +
                    "\t\t\t<td>"+dslr.getDslrId()+"</td>\n" +
                    "\t\t</tr>\n" +
                    "\t\t<tr>\n" +
                    "\t\t\t<td>model:</td>\n" +
                    "\t\t\t<td><input type=\"text\" name=\"dslr_model\" value=\""+dslr.getModel()+"\"></td>\n" +
                    "\t\t</tr>\n" +
                    "\t\t<tr>\n" +
                    "\t\t\t<td>price:</td>\n" +
                    "\t\t\t<td><input type=\"text\" name=\"dslr_price\" value=\""+dslr.getPrice()+"\"></td>\n" +
                    "\t\t</tr>\n" +
                    "\t\t<tr>\n" +
                    "\t\t\t<td>description:</td>\n" +
                    "\t\t\t<td><textarea name=\"dslr_description\" cols=\"30\" rows=\"10\">"+dslr.getDescription()+"</textarea></td>\n" +
                    "\t\t</tr>\n" +
                    "\t</table>\n" +
                    "</form>\n" +
                    "<input type=\"submit\" value=\"saveform\">" ;

            request.getSession().setAttribute("generatedResponse",tempHTML);
            request.setAttribute("generatedResponse",tempHTML);
            request.getRequestDispatcher("/dslrs.jsp").forward(request, response);
        }else {
            // SQLException
        }

        /**
         *  findAll()
          */
    } else {

        List<DSLR> dslrs = dslrDAO.findAll();
        if (dslrs != null) {
            tempHTML = "<table class=\"table\" bgcolor=\"#000000\" border=\"0\" cellpadding=\"0\" cellspacing=\"0\">\n" +
                    "    <tr bgcolor=\"#FFFFFF\" nowrap=\"\">\n" +
                    "        <td>Id</td>\n" +
                    "        <td>Model</td>\n" +
                    "        <td>Price</td>\n" +
                    "    </tr>\n" ;
            for (Iterator<DSLR> dslrIterator = dslrs.iterator(); dslrIterator.hasNext(); ) {
                DSLR next = dslrIterator.next();
                tempHTML += "<tr><td>" + next.getDslrId() +
                        "</td><td>" + next.getModel() +
                        "</td><td>" + next.getPrice() +
                        "</td><td><a href=\"javascript:get_dslr(" + next.getDslrId() + ") target=\"_self\"\">description " +
                        "</td><td><a href=\"" + "s?id=" + next.getDslrId() + "\">modify</a></td></tr>";
            }
            tempHTML += "</table>";

            request.getSession().setAttribute("generatedResponse",tempHTML);
            request.setAttribute("generatedResponse",tempHTML);
            request.getRequestDispatcher("/dslrs.jsp").forward(request, response);
        }else {
            //SQLException
        }
    }
```

**new JSP:**
...

```
${generatedResponse}
```

...

**Chrome:**

[image]

Comment: You can use [EL](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/1.4/tutorial/doc/JSPIntro7.html) in jsp to avoid Scriptlet : `{generatedResponse}`

Comment: Is it 1999 again?  I thought that putting HTML and CSS in servlets was discredited back then.  I'd put the HTML in Javascript and only return a flag to hide/show it with jQuery.

Comment: use search feature next time :)

Comment: @MironBalcerzak, Actually I did use, some parts of code was taken here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4253660/passing-object-from-jsp-to-servlet

Answer (score 0):

You can not customize the font of `textarea`. So make it like this..

```
<tr bgcolor=\"#ffffff\"><td bgcolor=\"#cccccc\" nowrap=\"\">description:</td><td>&nbsp;<textarea name=\"description\" cols=\"25\" rows=\"6\">"+dslr.getDescription()+"</td></tr>
```