# NullPointerException when passing object from jsp to Servlet

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, nullpointerexception

I am trying to pass the my DTO object from jsp to servlet using session object but i'm getting null pointer exception initially i tried with request object which is giving same error hence i moved to session object.

### in first servlet

```
request.getSession().setAttribute("datadto", dataDTO);
request.getRequestDispatcher("success.jsp").forward(request, response);
```

### in jsp

```
<% 
        DataDTO dataDTO = (DataDTO) request.getAttribute("datadto");
        HttpSession session420 = request.getSession();
        session420.setAttribute("object", dataDTO);
%>
```

### in second servlet

```
HttpSession session=request.getSession(false);
DataDTO dataDTO = (DataDTO) session.getAttribute("object");

MyService myService = ServiceFactory.getMyService();
myService.generateExcel(dataDTO); <--nullpointerexception
```

on googling i found the following [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4253660/passing-object-from-jsp-to-servlet)
I implemented as he said still i'm getting null pointer exception

### in jsp

```
DataDTO dataDTO = myService.getData(keyword, nor);
String myObjectId = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
request.getSession().setAttribute(myObjectId, dataDTO);
request.setAttribute("myObjectId", myObjectId);
```

### in second servlet

```
String myObjectId = request.getParameter("myObjectId");
Object myObject = request.getSession().getAttribute(myObjectId);
DataDTO dataDTO = (DataDTO) myObject;
request.getSession().removeAttribute(myObjectId);
```

please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your DTO is already set in `session` in your first servlet. So, just **remove** this code from your JSP because it's actually removing the DTO from `session` by setting it to `null`.

```
<% 
    DataDTO dataDTO = (DataDTO) request.getAttribute("datadto");
    HttpSession session420 = request.getSession();
    session420.setAttribute("object", dataDTO);
%>
```

And retrieve the DTO in your second servlet by using the original *key* name `datadto`

```
HttpSession session=request.getSession(false);
DataDTO dataDTO = (DataDTO) session.getAttribute("datadto");
```

Comment: i'm getting nullpointer exception in the second servlet at exportExcel()

Comment: I removed as you said and  placed below code 

HttpSession session=request.getSession(false);
DataDTO dataDTO = (DataDTO) session.getAttribute("datadto"); in second servlet

Comment: Are you sure datadto is not null in the first servlet? Show us more code?

Comment: in first servlet
DataDTO dataDTO = myService.getData(keyword,nor);
request.getSession().setAttribute("datadto", dataDTO);
if(dataDTO !=null)
request.getRequestDispatcher("success.jsp").forward(request, response);
else
request.getRequestDispatcher("failure.jsp").forward(request, response);

Comment: Please share your full code. The error could be at someplace else. Perhaps you're overwriting the value someplace else too.

Comment: yes you are right error at some other MyService class

Comment: how to convert object to string and string to object as said in the following link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4253660/passing-object-from-jsp-to-servlet

Answer (score 0):

In the `JSP` you are saying .

```
 DataDTO dataDTO = (DataDTO) request.getAttribute("datadto");
```

Instead it should be `request.getSession().getAttribute("datadto");`

Your code modified in the below line

```
<% 
        DataDTO dataDTO = (DataDTO) request.getSession().getAttribute("datadto");
        HttpSession session420 = request.getSession();
        session420.setAttribute("object", dataDTO);
%>
```

Comment: in first servlet
----------------
request.getSession().setAttribute("datadto", dataDTO);


in jsp
------
<% 
DataDTO dataDTO = (DataDTO) request.getSession().getAttribute("datadto");
HttpSession session420 = request.getSession();
session420.setAttribute("object", dataDTO);
%>

in second servlet
-----------------
HttpSession session=request.getSession(false);
DataDTO dataDTO = (DataDTO) session.getAttribute("object");

Comment: in first servlet
----------------
request.getSession().setAttribute("datadto", dataDTO);

in jsp
------
<% DataDTO dataDTO = (DataDTO) request.getSession().getAttribute("datadto");
HttpSession session420 = request.getSession();
session420.setAttribute("object", dataDTO); %>

in second servlet
-----------------
HttpSession session=request.getSession(false); DataDTO dataDTO = (DataDTO) session.getAttribute("object");

Comment: @rock : I was referring your code as follows. In the first servlet you are setting the value as follows request.getSession().setAttribute("datadto", dataDTO); and in the first jsp you are saying  DataDTO dataDTO = (DataDTO) request.getAttribute("datadto");. how will u get the value. In the servlet you are setting the value in session and in the jsp you are fetching the value from request. That is what i have shown in my answer. Please correct me if i am wrong