# Passing values from servlet to html to servlet

Tags: html, jsp, servlets

i know i am asking a bit silly question., but please guys help me and let me know.
Scanario:
      I have 2 servlets and 1 html file.
  1st servlet is redireted to html file which on submit redirects to 2nd servlet.
I need a attribute value from 1st servlet.
I know., if we can use RequestDispatcher between two servlets., but here situattion is different

Please anyone let me know how can i get attribute value from first servlet to second servlet

Note: In First servlet., through anchor tag, HTML page is referred

Comment: Another related question on the subject: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4253660/passing-object-from-jsp-to-servlet/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [HttpSession](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpSession.html) for it. For example,

```
public class Servlet1 extends HttpServlet {

    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) {
        req.getSession().setAttribute("attribute", "value");
        // do stuff...
    }

}

public class Servlet2 extends HttpServlet {

    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) {
        String value = (String) req.getSession().getAttribute("attribute");
        req.getSession().removeAttribute("attribute");
        // do stuff...
    }

}
```