# JSTL forEach tag not iteraring over collection

Tags: java, jsp, jstl

I have some problems with creating a jsp file. I would like to use JSTL in order to display a collection somehow. First, I have created a java code inside my jsp:

```
<% for(int i = 0; i < ((List<BookPosition>)request.getAttribute("books")).size(); i+=1) { %>  
        <label>Test</label>
<% } %>
```

Then, I've create a JSTL snippet.

```
<c:forEach var="book" items="$(books)">
        <label>Test</label>
</c:forEach>
```

Unfortunately, the first one outputs correct number of labels (24) and the JSTL version only one label (despite the collection contains exaclty 24 items).

Why?

Comment: What do you think `$(books)` represents? Why do you think so?

Comment: No idea. I am new to JSP / JSTL and found some snippets, that at servlet side I should set: `request.setAttribute("books", myBookCollection);`, use dispatcher to forward request to jsp and then loop should work. F.e: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4255741/5417374

Comment: Looks like you are using parentheses () instead of curly braces {} - try ${books}

Comment: I don't see the notation `$()` anywhere there. Check the syntax. I'm voting to close as typo.

Comment: Yes.. parentheses... I have overlookes that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[EL expressions](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnahu.html) are written like this : `${ myExpression }`

```
<c:forEach var="book" items="${ books }">
        <label>Test</label>
</c:forEach>
```

---

Now, if you also want to keep track of the number of printed values, you could use a counter using the [varStatus](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/jstl/1.1/docs/tlddocs/c/forEach.html) attribute in your **JSTL Core Tag**:

```
<c:forEach var="book" items="${ books }" varStatus="counter">
        <label><c:out value="${ counter.count }"/>. Test</label>
</c:forEach>
```