# passing value from java to jsp

Tags: java, jsp, struts2

My java class is below. how to get the value of the string returnStatus to JSP .
Kindly let me know how to pass this returnStatus value to JSP as my JSp is showing blank even though it is mapped in struts

```
public class WCSOrdersListAction extends ActionSupport{

private String returnStatus;

public String execute() throws SQLException, ClassNotFoundException {

setReturnStatus("SUCCESS"); 

}

return SUCCESS;

public String getReturnStatus() {
    return returnStatus;
}


public void setReturnStatus(String returnStatus) {
    this.returnStatus = returnStatus;
}
}
```

Comment: Please can you show your JSP and struts mapping

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Passing an object from JSP page back to Servlet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4253660/passing-an-object-from-jsp-page-back-to-servlet)

Comment: <title>WCS Order - eCcelerator Tools</title>
</head>

<body>
<s:if test="returnStatus == 'SUCCESS'"> 
 <s:form action="WCSOrderDisplay" name="form" method="post" > 
 <a href="WCSOrderDisplay" id="WCSOrderDisplay" >
 <div align="center" class="content-text">
</div>
 <div id="tableWrap">
<div align="center" class="content-text">
   <table border="1" cellpadding="10" class="table-db-results">
      </table>
   </div>
   </div>
  </s:form>
 </s:if>
<%@ include file="footer.jsp" %>
</body>

Comment: Please edit the question rather than trying to post code in comments; it's essentially illegible. Also, please format your code properly, and post actual working code, which this isn't.