# How to get the previous request form that returns an object to a Servlet?

Tags: java, html, jsp, servlets

[[Passing an object from JSP page back to Servlet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4253660/passing-an-object-from-jsp-page-back-to-servlet][1])

From the top reviewed answer of the question above,
What does Form preprocessing Servlet and Form postprocessing Servlet mean? Where do I put it in my servlet? Do I put it on the same method? Do I call preprocessing Servlet first then proceed with the form submission of my JSP file and then proceed to the postprocessing file?

Answer (score 1):

You write both the code in the same servlet in the sequence mentioned below:

A. Get the request parameters from the request (which may have values of HTML form elements and explicit request parameters), as mentioned in the **Form postprocessing** part

```
String myObjectId = request.getParameter("myObjectId");
Object myObject = request.getSession().getAttribute(myObjectId);
request.getSession().removeAttribute(myObjectId);
// ...
```

B. Perform some business logic and forward the request to some JSP, as mentioned in the **Form preprocessing** part

```
String myObjectId = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
request.getSession().setAttribute(myObjectId, myObject);
request.setAttribute("myObjectId", myObjectId);
request.getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/page.jsp").forward(request, response);
```

Comment: thank you, but will it be in the same method though? If not, how and where will you call both methods?